# Why do software updates exist?

Tags: performance, compilation, updates, software-distribution

I know this may sound crazy but hear me out...

Say you have a game and you want to update it (add new features / redecorate for seasonal themes / add LTMs etc.) Now, instead of editing your code and then waiting days for your app market provider (Google/Microsoft/Apple etc.) to approve the update and roll out the changes, why not:

1. Put all of your code into a database
2. Remove all of your existing code from your code files
3. Add code which can run code from a database (reads it in and `eval()`s it)

This way, there'd be no need for software updates unless you wanted to change your database-related code, and you could simply update your database to change what the app does when it's live.

**My Question: Why hasn't this been done?**

For example:

Fortnite (a real game) often has LTMs (Limited Time Modes) which are available for a few weeks and are then removed. Generally, the software updates are ~ 5GB and take a lot of time unless your broadband is fast. If the code was fetched from a database and then executed, there'd be no need for these updates and the changes could be instantaneous.

**EDIT**: (In response to the close votes)

I'm looking for facts and statistics to back up reasons rather than just pure opinions. Answers like 'I think this would be good/bad ... ' aren't needed (that's why there's comments); answers like are 'This would be good/bad as this fact shows that ...' are much better and desired.

Comment: Because then any idiot could get into your database, put malevolent code in, and raise havoc? Because you still have the same issue of updating that database? Because it's an extremely poor idea? Because performance would be miserable? Because they created the store review policies to keep bad people from putting codes on everyone's phones and computers?

Comment: because it would be an act of insanity.

Comment: And as for your game example - 5gb? Go make a sandwich while it downloads. A little patience is a good price for an infinitely more stable and secure platform.

Comment: @KenWhite :( For the first question, you would just need your database to be protected and secure, and if your game is very popular, then it's likely that you already have lots of security in place for your existing databases. 2. Yes, but only *you* would have to wait and not all of your customers/clients/users. 3. Why? 4. Maybe, but I think it depends. 5. That's valid.

Comment: @KaiQing "I know this may sound crazy but hear me out..." :) Also, time is a good price but that's no reason to *not* do it ... the less time it takes for a user to begin playing your game, the happier they are, which is always a good thing :)

Comment: @KenWhite I was just wondering what challenges there would be in doing it ... also, there's only one database request per file, and then all of the strings are `eval()`ed, so there's not as many database requests as you're implying...

Comment: Have fun debugging.

Comment: @MikeTheLiar That's valid :) However, if the development team kept a normal (not dependent on database) version of the code and tested and developed that first, before releasing it to the database, wouldn't the debugging aspect mostly be solved?

Comment: I say you should simply develop this technology.  If it is successful, then you will revolutionize the market.

Comment: lol have fun debugging divergent code

Comment: Relevant DWTF article http://thedailywtf.com/articles/the-inner-json-effect

Comment: @MikeTheLiar But it wouldn't be divergent unless there were problems in fetching code from the database, which is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: @Amy Is that sarcastic??

Comment: @MikeTheLiar How??? The only similarity I see here is that code is being stored on databases ... otherwise, they're completely different.

Comment: @Adi219 I was not being sarcastic.  If you stand by your ideas, you should put them into practice.  (This is generally how innovation happens - someone comes up with a new idea that no one else is doing, and does it)

Comment: You're essentially checking out the latest version of the code and interpreting/compiling it every time you execute. Being able to update code without deploying it is basically pushing to a Git repo just with more steps involved.

Comment: @Amy Have social anxieties so I wasn't sure ... thanks! :))

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you're proposing shipping the diff between the release and previous versions and having customers run a `git pull` or equivalent. A couple issues: you would need to ship a compiler/ interpreter and your source code would be open to all of your users, which is a problem for proprietary systems. I guess you could ship binary diffs instead to get around those problems

Comment: @user3080953 (I'm assuming diff means difference) There'd be no need to ship a compiler/interpreter as that's handled by the app market provider, also the source code wouldn't be available as the database would be private and secured against attacks, but the binary bit makes sense.

Comment: @Adi219 I was thinking about this last night.  [Did you know that experts originally ignored or derided public key encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59537/how-come-public-key-cryptography-wasnt-discovered-earlier).  Sometimes, the experts are very wrong and should be ignored.

Comment: @Amy Honestly, that's made my day (night?) :-) Your link to the post about public key encryption was quite interesting ... thanks for spending time on this :))

Answer (score 0):

There are few challenges in your suggested approach.

- putting everything in database will make increase the size of db. But that doest affect much.
- If all the code is there in db, its possible to decompile your software and get a way to connect to your code?
- too much performance overhead of `eval`s. Precompiled code is optimized for their respective runtime
- multiple versions? What to do when you want to have multiple versions of your software?

The main reason updates exists is they are easy to maintain, flexible and allows the developer to ship fastest optimized tool.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Put all of your code into a database
> 2. Remove all of your existing code from your code files
> 3. Add code which can run code from a database (reads it in and eval()s it)
>
> My Question: Why hasn't this been done?

This is exactly how every game works already.

Each time you launch a game, an executable binary game engine (which you describe in step 3) already reads the rest of your code (often some embedded language like LUA) from a "database" (the file system) and "evals" (interprets) it to run the game, as well as assets like level geometry, textures, sounds and music.

You're talking about introducing a layer of abstraction (a real database) between the engine and its data to hide some of your assets, but the database stores its data *on the file system*, so you really haven't gained anything, you've just changed the way the data is encoded at rest and queried during runtime, and introduce a *ton* of overhead in both cases.

On the other hand, you're intentionally cheating your way through the app reviewal process this way, and whatever real technical problems you would have are moot, because your app would not be allowed in the app store. The entire point of the app reviewal process is to prevent people from shipping unverified unreviewed code to users, and if your program is obviously designed to circumvent this, your app will be rejected.

> Fortnite (a real game) often has LTMs (Limited Time Modes) which are available for a few weeks and are then removed. Generally, the software updates are ~ 5GB and take a lot of time unless your broadband is fast.

Fotenite will have a small binary executable that is the game engine. Updates to this binary will account for a fraction of a percentage of that 5GB. The rest will be some kind of interpreted/embedded language describing the game's levels (also a tiny fraction) and then assets which account for the rest (geometry, textures, sound, music).

> If the code was fetched from a database and then executed, there'd be no need for these updates and the changes could be instantaneous

This makes no sense. If you move that entire 5GB from the file system into a database, you still have to transfer around 5GB worth of database updates. 5GB of data in a database still lives as 5GB of data on the file system, it's just that you can't access it directly anymore. You have to transfer around the *exact same amount of data*, regardless of how you store it.